# What is the definition of a single valued function

Tags: notation, terminology

this is potentially a dumb question but I am a touch confused about some terminology. I'm reading Ahlfor's complex analysis, and I am in a section on integrals of harmonic functions.

I may be being dense, but I am not sure what he is referring to when he calls a harmonic function "single-valued". For context,

> A real-vaued function u(z), defined and single valued in $\Omega$, is said to be harmonic...

Comment: The definition is on page 22 in a footnote.  (Now to find out what "pleonastic" means.... *sigh*)

Comment: By Gauss's Beard... you even know the footnotes! Although I have a feeling I'll be in the same boat by the end. Also, that is quite a word. I believe I shall employ it in the future. A bit pleonastic though.

Comment: Um, I hadn't opened the book in 20 years.  I looked single-value in the index and it said page 22 so ... (I thought "single valued" would mean constant but that didn't seem to make sense so I looked it up...)

Comment: Huh, my edition (2nd) doesn't have it in the index.

Comment: I've got the third edition.    So... wasn't in the footnote on page 22?

Comment: Indeed it was. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that every element maps to exactly one value. Because in complex analysis you can sometimes deal with things like $\sqrt[n]{x}$, which has $n$ solutions if $x$ is non-zero. Some authors call such functions multi-valued functions.

So the text just means it is a "proper" function.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I'm still used to real functional terminology where we are safe from such affronts.